# Is the Greenskin Invasion defeated at Nuln the same one that captured the High-King of the Dwarfs, Kurgan Ironbeard?

Tags: lore, wfrp-4e

I'm creating a [mindmap](https://atlas.mindmup.com/dorianturba/warhammer_world/index.html) of the background of the world of WFRP (in French) and I want to know if those two events in the history of the Old World are linked.

The [Greenskin Invasion](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Nuln) came from the south and was defeated by Sigmar and allied tribes. In the story of the [ancient hammer Ghal-Maraz offered to Sigmar](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Sigmar#fn_1g_back), he defeated a Black-Orc leading a group after capturing the High-King of the Dwarfs Kurgan Ironbeard.

Are the Black Orc Warboss known as Vagraz Headstomper and his troops part of the Greenskin invasion mention above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**.

[Sigmar - History](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Sigmar#fn_5a_back):

> Sigmar is believed to have been born **-30 IC**.

[Sigmar - Sigmar and Ironbeard](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Sigmar#fn_1g_back):

> At the age of **fifteen**, Sigmar led a retaliatory raid upon a Greenskin
>   tribe in retribution for their prior attack on an Unberogen holding.

[Sigmar - The Battle of Black Fire Pass](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Sigmar#fn_5e_back):

> It was in **-1 IC** that Man and Dwarf finally joined each other's host at Black Fire Pass

Sigmar saved Kurgan Ironbeard at the age of 15. The events of the Greenskin Invasion described in the page on Nuln were after he had unified the tribes of man, shortly before the Battle of Black Fire Pass, 
fourteen years after the defeat of Vagraz Headstomper against Sigmar.